# Functional Programming Dependencies: How to share dependencies between functions that aren't connected together direct

Tags: functional-programming, functional-dependencies, functional-java

these different functions are composed together like so

```
f1 -> f2 -> f3 -> f4 -> f5
```

I need to add two new functions fx and fy around f3 like so:

```
f1 -> f2 -> fx -> f3 -> fy -> f4 -> f5
```

so I need to pre-process the argument for f3 and then post-process the output from f3

here function fx makes a change and fy reverts the change back, but fy needs additional details from fx to be able to revert, to know what values to revert to for example

the problem is that function fx needs to produce two outputs

```
first: output that is needed by f3
second: output that is needed by fy
```

Question: 
How to share dependencies between functions that are not connected together direct, 
is there a spacial way/technique to solve this?

FYI, I'm using Java8

Comment: may be introduce  fk which is fx -> f3 -> fy

Comment: Use [arrows](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html). I don't program in Java. Hence, I don't know if there are any Java libraries for arrow-based computations. A quick Google search didn't yield any results either. However, it shouldn't be too difficult to implement it yourself. If you update your question with some concrete code examples then perhaps I could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use some type `A` for all function return values; you will need to sort out the real types yourself.

Here's the intention as you described it:

- Function `fx` will yield two parameters, let's call them `a` and `b`.
- Function `f3` will process the value `a` and yield `a'`.
- Finally, `fy` will consume `a'` and `b` and produce `c`.

Let's see how can we achieve that (I will write pseudocode for type signatures):

1. Define `fy` as a function that takes two parameters and returns one:

   ```
   (A, A) => A
   ```
2. Define `fyp` (short for "fy preprocessed") as a function that takes some preprocessing function `p` and performs the logic of your `fy`, but with first parameter preprocessed with `p`. We will write this in the form `P => FY`, where `P` is the type signature of the preprocessing function, and `FY` is the type signature of `fy`:

   ```
   P => FY, which expands to  
   (A => A) => (A, A) => A
   ```

   So the implementation of this function should take the preprocessing function `p` of type `A => A` as input, and perform the logic of `fy` (this is the right hand side, `(A, A) => A`... note how it corresponds to the signature of `fy`), but before performing the logic, it will map the first parameter of `fy` with `p`. Here's some Scala implementation for reference (I'm not so good with Java):

   ```
   val fyp: (A => A) => ((A, A)) => A =              
     f => fyuParams => performFyLogic((f(fyuParams._1), fyuParams._2))
   ```

   where `performFyLogic` is the actual processing logic of your `fy` function.
3. Define the final composition as:

   ```
   f1 -> f2 -> fx -> fyp(f3)
   ```

Here's full Scala implementation for reference (again, don't know Java 8 that well):

```
val f1: Int => Int = _ + 1
val f2: Int => Int = _ + 2
val f3: Int => Int = _ + 3

val fx: Int => (Int, Int) = i => (i + 4, i + 5)

// let's assume that the original fy simply sums up its two parameters
val fyp: (Int => Int) => ((Int, Int)) => Int =
  f => fyArgs => f(fyArgs._1) + fyArgs._2

val composed1 = f1 andThen f2 andThen f3
println(composed1(42)) // 48

val composed2 = f1 andThen f2 andThen fx andThen fyp(f3)
println(composed2(42)) // 102

// because:
// f1 -> f2 -> fx = (42 + 1 + 2 + 4, 41 + 1 + 2 + 5) = (49, 50)
// fyp(f3)((49, 50)) = (49 + 3) + 50 = 102
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating fk function that wraps f3 by calling fx before and fy after it, this way I was able to share the bit of state needed, which is similar to arrows as suggested by Aadit.